# Is Windows 10 less respectful to Ctrl+Alt+Del?

Tags: windows-10

Sometimes I get my W10 into a glitchy state that prevents or terribly slows app switching, but allow some things like switching virtual desktops or working in the open app with ease and no lag. Sometimes the mouse disappears as well.

During these problems I have tried ctrl+alt+del to reduce clutter and just reach the controls to do a restart. However, that key combination never had an effect in that state. I have the feeling that it would work in older versions, as it has always working while the OS is somewhat responsive to input.

Is the ctrl+alt+del signal interpreted in some "softer" way than before? Or is the called routine somehow integrated deeper into the system, making it suffer more of the issues that other programs soffer from?

Comment: I think I've seen the same behaviour going back to Vista, maybe XP, so this is nothing new. It just depends on what was stalling your system in the first place (if it's GPU [driver] related, that really interferes with the desktop session switching that CAD does - this got slower since Vista, though somewhat faster again with 7). It hasn't been a truly hard interrupt since the Win9x days, IME.

Comment: What you are describing is a system that has run out of the resources necessary to execute machine code in a timely manner. It may be running out of ram... ram and swap space... storage space... or it could even be that the CPU is being overworked. This is also not something limited to Windows 10 or even XP and newer... or even Windows... though it was actually more common before Vista. The reason has nothing to do with Windows and everything to do with multi-core CPUs. But no matter how many cores your CPU has it's still possible to queue more jobs than the CPU can run in a timely manner.

Comment: [Watch this](https://youtu.be/THqcAa1bbFU) for a very simplified understanding of process scheduling. Understand that a 4-core CPU effectively is 4 separate CPUs in the context of this video. What you are experiencing, most likely, is too many very high priority jobs filling up the queues. CTRL+ALT+DELETE is an interrupt (in fact, all user input is). It normally jumps the line and goes straight to the head of the queue. But when there are more interrupts at once than CPUs... they still get queued. Which is when CTRL+ALT+DELETE stops working as well.